# SharePoint online Active directory

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint server the users synched from the company active directory.

In SharePoint online , from where it sync the users?

- Is there main AD and BU for each tenant?
- Is there independent AD for each tenant?
- How Microsoft build and manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 uses Azure AD for its directory. From your perspective, this AD is your private AD. It can be administered from your Office 365 Admin portal or by using PowerShell. You can use Azure AD Connect or AD FS to sync user credentials from an on-prem AD.

If your tenant is named "test" then your user's initial domain is user@test.onmicrosoft.com. After you add a custom domain it is then user@mydomain.com.

Set up directory synchronization for Office 365
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/set-up-directory-synchronization

Comment: thanks, it is still not clear, each tenant has independent AD!!! is  , how Microsoft build this? I think it is one main AD and each tenant has its BU? please Do you have any article confirm that each tenant has its own AD ?

Comment: any update please!!

Comment: Each tenant has its own AD "as a tenant". Physically, each tenant does not have its own server (VM or otherwise) or its own instance of Windows Server AD.   See if this helps: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-1-an-introduction/  " Azure AD is not Windows Server Active Directory running on Virtual Machines in Microsoft Azure."

Comment: Back to the original question... "In SharePoint online , from where it sync the users?" It syncs from AzureAD (running behind Office 365), and Azure AD can sync from your on-prem Windows AD.  "How Microsoft build and manage it?" You would need to ask Microsoft. Is this a curiosity question, or is there a specific concern?

Comment: Back to the original question... again... I'm assuming you are asking about SharePoint User Profiles being sync'd from AD.

Comment: thanks, Azure domain is not like Windows domain, how it is structure? any link talk about the azure AD infrastructure and components